# SQL Server - Using Substring to Pull Multiple Sets of Data from One Source

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a script to pull out data from existing stored procedures. What I want to do is pull out all connections from a single source.

I.E. we have a select in a stored procedure. That select is as follows,

```
Select data from dbo.table1 t1
inner join dbo.table2 t2 on t1.pk=t2.pk
inner join dbo.table3 t3 on t2.pk=t3.pk
```

I want to pull out dbo.table1, dbo.table2, and dbo.table3

Edit:

To clear up, from that select statement, I want to pull out dbo.table1, dbo.table2, and dbo.table3 into an output or insert it into a table. Basically, I'm trying to get a list of all tables from all stored procedures.

Also, sysdepends does not work for every stored procedure due to some of the stored procedures existing at a linked server.

Comment: What do you mean pull out?  That means nothing.

Comment: Your question (well actually there isn't a question) doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can do a select t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col2..

Comment: Just modified it to try to make some more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx) for SQL Server 2014 or [`sp_depends`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx) for previous versions.

Comment: That's something I didn't know about so thanks. However, while it works for the current server, I also need to grab references to other linked servers.

Comment: well, get list of linked servers and then walk through all of them and query same views (if your linked servers are SQL Servers)

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that current stored procs on server a contain select statements to tables on server b. I want to grab those references as well.